# Stereoisomerism

Tags: organic-chemistry

The C-C bond in alkanes can freely rotate , then how can you call 2 alkanes (having atleast one chiral carbon) as diastereomers if they have different arrangements of groups (atoms)  in space & are Non super imposable on thier mirror images because they can rotate around C-C bond and become same as the other molecule

For example
 2-bromo 2-methyl 1-phenyl ethanol 
Here there are 2 chiral carbon , one with phenyl (let us call this First chiral carbon) and another with bromine (second chiral carbon). In first chiral carbon,  if we interchange the position of phenyl and OH group, we get 2 structures which are  not mirror images of each other and hence my sir told me that they are diastereomers. But I think the C-C bond between the two chiral carbon can freely  rotate ,then by rotating the C-C bond keeping the 2nd Chiral carbon fixed we get the same structure . So I got confused here please help.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. Please clarify your question. Perhaps provide an example. One center of chirality does not a diastereomer make.

Comment: Also please split your question in two or three sentences, with some punctuation? Its barely understandable.

Comment: Sorry I have changed the question you can see

Comment: You can't change the stereochemistry of a chiral centre by rotation of single bonds. So, you cannot make the two diastereomers "the same", no matter how much you twist and turn it. Make a model and try it out.

Comment: Please explain how otherwise send any 3d animation of it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "3D animation" per your request. Changing the configuration at C<sub>1</sub> in structure **1** produces diastereomer **2**. They are diastereomers (constitutional or structural isomers) because they have the same atom connectivity but different arrangements in space. The same is true of the enantiomeric pair *ent*-**1** and ent-**2**. The diagonal relationships , **1** <--> ent-**2** and **2** <--> *ent*-**1**, are diastereomeric as well.
[image]